# Why I get error while I write symbols before <<EOF>>?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, flex-lexer, lex

Why I get the following error:

> unrecognized rule

while I try to do it:

```
%x CS
\"                      {BEGIN(CS);}
<CS>(.*)<<EOF>>         {printf("Error"); exit(0);}   *** ERROR:unrecognized rule 
<CS>\"                  {BEGIN(INITIAL); return;}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`<<EOF>>` can only be used as a complete pattern. It is not a pattern element. It is the only (f)lex pattern which matches no input, which means that it must return 0 or otherwise arrange for the parse to terminate.

(F)lex does not offer a mechanism to recognise a pattern at the end of input. That's not usually a problem because it can generally be handled by recognising tokens which do not appear at the end of input; once those are recognised, any token which also matches the pattern must be at the end.

While that does provide an almost universal solution, in particular cases such as your snippet, there are even simpler solutions. For example, the following will recognise quoted strings and produce an error for unterminated strings.

```
%x CS
%%
\"              { BEGIN(CS); }
<CS>[^"\n]+     { /* string contents */ }
<CS>\"          { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<CS>\n          |
<CS><<EOF>>     { /* error */ }
```

In this case, we don't allow newlines in strings so an unterminated string error could mean either a string not completed within the line or a string terminated by end-of-file *before a newline is encountered*. That's not very likely because non-empty text files should always end with a newline character, but we always need to consider corner cases. (If we wanted to allow multiline strings, we could just remove the exclusion of `\n` from the first `<CS>` pattern. Normally we would add rules to recognise escape sequences.)